# Frequency count method

Tags: frequency, frequency-analysis, time-frequency

I'm a newbie in data structures, this question appeared in a model question paper.

> Calculate the frequency count of the statement x = x+1; in the following code segment

```
for (i = 0; i< n; i++)
    for (j = 0; j< n; j*=2)
        x = x + 1;
```

My question is would (*) affect the frequency count? There are no brackets.

Answer (score 3):

`j*=2` means `j=j*2` (multiplication). But since `j` starts at 0, it will always stay 0. You have an infinite loop.

The  brackets can usually be implicit if you have just one line.

It would be easier to answer knowing in what language you are working.

Comment: Its just C language